# NSTableView + NSArrayController + Core Data with issue "Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nstablecellview

I'm having a issue with custom cell view table `NSTableView + NSArrayController + Core Data`. Saving the items to core data without problems but if i want to refresh the table view after getting notification that `NSArrayController` changed (init loading and displaying the table are without problems), i get the Exception `"Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil"` and breakpoint is as in the photo [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89KCD.png). With Debugging i saw that the count of items in `arrangedObjects` of `NSArrayController` did change correctly. Why did i get this Exception in the method `- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`

Is it possible that i get the notification of changing in `NSArrayController` before the saving items in core data done? Somehow some properties of new saving item were nil when i try displaying them on the table?

Some code of my `TableController`

```
@interface TableController : NSController <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>

@property IBOutlet NSArrayController* arrayController;
@property IBOutlet TableView *tableView;
@property IBOutlet NSSearchField *searchField;
@property PasteboardItem *actualItem;

- (BOOL)isFiltering;
- (BOOL)copySelectedItemToPasteboard;

- (IBAction)clickOnRemoveButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)clickOnCopyButton:(id)sender;

@end


@implementation TableController

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        _arrayController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
        [_arrayController setManagedObjectContext:context];
        [_arrayController setEntityName:@"PasteboardItem"];
        [_arrayController fetch:self];
        [_arrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"arrangedObjects"]) {
        [_tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Table View with two different custom cell views:

[image: xib file]

Exception with break point:

[image: method with breakpoint]

Saving to core data is OK:

[image: success saving in core data]

Comment: `[pbItem mainText]` seems to be nil. Did you save something there?

Comment: Yes it's nil. But the reloadData will be only called if the saving process to core data finished, right? But as i said the saving process was ended successfully. Because if i break the app and start it again, the table will be display correctly.

Comment: Is the array controller bound to the managedObjectContext you are saving?  I'm confused why you'd do that and not bind the table to the array controller as well.  Regardless, if it is bound, arrangedObjects will change as soon as you add a new object, regardless of whether the MOC is saved.

Comment: OK now i understand why i got nil while trying to set value to the textfied. Just another question: is it possible to bind the table with multiple custom row to the array controller as in my case?

Comment: Yes.  But even with binding to an array controller to be the table's datasource, you will often need to implement a delegate to decide which custom row view is used depending on the object type that array controller provides for the row index.